# What "evidence" is Gobber referring to?

Tags: how-to-train-your-dragon

In *How to Train Your Dragon: The Hidden World* (2019), Gobber says to Hiccup:

> Gobber: Those bloody Hobgobblers. I swear they're popping up faster than rabbits. I think they want to eat me. **Evidence** would suggest I'm tasty.

What "evidence" is Gobber referring to?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

He's referring to the fact that a dragon ate his hand, we even get a glimpse of this story in the first film:

> **Gobber:** ...And with one twist, he took my hand, and swallowed it whole. And I saw the look on his face: I was delicious. He must have passed the word, because it wasn't a month before another one of them took my leg.
>
> <sub>*How to Train Your Dragon*</sub>